# Recursion in NASM: Fibonacci

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, nasm, fibonacci

I am having a hard time getting recursion to work. Well, recursion for a n! factorial calculator wasn't that hard, took me about half a day to figure it out.

```
   mov eax, [input]
   call factorialator

   jmp quit
 ;   
factorialator:
   cmp eax, 0
   je return
   push eax
   dec eax
   call factorialator
  ;
   pop eax
   imul ebx, eax
   ret
;
return:
   mov ebx, 1
   ret
```

Now, that function calls itself with n = n-1 and pushes n every time until n = 0, when it multiplies all of them. *Easy peasy*

But now, that I have to call the function with (n-1) AND (n-2) I can't imagine how that would work, since I have to manage return addresses, the stack, the values. All I know that every time when it subtracts either 1 or 2 and the result is 1, then it should inc a counter which will then give us the result.

so return with n-1 until n-1 = 1, in which case return n-2 and then again n-1. I am just **so** confused and been struggling on this for the better of 2 days now.

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Write the code in a higher level language (or pseudo code) first, using named variables for temps. That way it'll be clearer what you need to do in the asm version.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same principle. In the factorial case you save `N` temporarily because you need it later to multiply `fact(N-1)` by.
In the Fibonacci series case you also save `N` (or `N-1`) temporarily, because you need it later to calculate `N-2` so that you can calculate `fib(N-2)`.

An x86 implementaion might look like this:

```
fib:
    cmp eax,1       ; Base case?
    jbe done        ; Yes => return n
    dec eax
    push eax        ; Save n-1 on the stack
    call fib        ; Calculate fib(n-1)
    xchg eax,[esp]  ; Place fib(n-1) on the stack, while retrieving n-1 into eax
    dec eax
    call fib        ; Calculate fib(n-2)
    add eax,[esp]   ; fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
    add esp,4       ; "Undo" the push operation
done:
    ret
```

Comment: beware that `xchg eax,[esp]` has an implicit `lock` prefix, and thus is quite a lot slower than using separate load/store instructions (using a scratch register like `mov edx,[esp]` / `mov [esp],eax` / `lea eax, [edx-1]`).  Of course if you cared about efficiency *at all* you'd compute Fib(n) iteratively with something like `add eax,edx` / `add edx,eax` in O(n) time instead of O(Fib(n)) time, as well as lower constant factors.  But in general it's dangerous to show examples using `xchg` with mem.